# Simple mechanics : Bar stuck to a point on the ground: Inertia problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, inertia

> So, given the following bar, stuck to the ground at point O, I know its mass, the angle it makes with the vertical axis that goes through the point O, I know the bar's length and its initial velocity, in the direction of the arrow ($\omega = 4~\text{rads/s}, m = 2~\text{kg}, l =0.5 ~\text{m}$)

I want to know if the bar actually passes through the vertical point.

[image]

What I have done, was to simplify the problem, by only looking at the center of mass of the bar:

[image]

The results: Now I can simply use the conservation of energy to understand that the initial kinematic energy must be equal to the point where there is only potential energy.
Solving for h, if h is better than the yellow line, then the center of mass (or in this case, the sphere) will go up the slope.

**My two questions:**

1. Is this a legit way of solving the problem? Do I need to account for the inertia of the bar? (In this case, $I = (ml^2)/3$ from the point O)
2. Will the normal force that the ground exerts on the bar always be the same ( = its weight) or does it change varying with Inertia / any angle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in principle, this is a valid approach to solving this problem; yes, you need to take into account the inertial moment of the bar, and no, the normal force (in the vertical direction) will change in general, as a function of angle.

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering how can I put the Inertial moment of the bar into play on what I am doing...

Comment: If initial rotational KE = $\frac12 I \omega^2$ is greater than the change in PE, the bar will pass the vertical.

Comment: What about the normal force that the ground exerts on the bar? Is it affected by Inertia? Shouldn't the weight always be the same?